# Different column widths with multicom

Tags: tables, multirow, width

[image: I want to recreate this table]

The 5th row is killing me. How can i determine the width of the rows? I manage to scrap up the code underneath.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{11.2cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
       \textbf{Fag:}   & \textbf{Dato:} 17.01.20 \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Prosjekt:}} \\
    \hline
        \textbf{Aktivitet:} & \textbf{Aktivitet nr: } \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{7cm}|p{7cm}}
         \textbf{Startdato:}  & \textbf{Sluttdato: }
        \end{tabular}} \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you want to achieve, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to determine the widths manually, latex will do it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Fag:}}   & \textbf{Dato:} 17.01.20 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|X|}{\textbf{Prosjekt:}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|X|}{\textbf{Aktivitet:}} & \textbf{Aktivitet nr: } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Startdato:}}  & \multicolumn{3}{|X|}{\textbf{Sluttdato:}}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Avhengighey:}} & \multicolumn{5}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Foregaende aktiviteter:}}\\
\cline{2-6}
 & \multicolumn{5}{|X|}{\textbf{Etterfolende aktiviteter:}}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you might want to use `\multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Startdato:}}  & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{\textbf{Sluttdato:}}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Avhengighey:}} & \multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Foregaende aktiviteter:}}\\
\cline{2-6}
 & \multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Etterfolende aktiviteter:}}\\
\hline`.

Comment: This removes the double vertical line in row 4 and row 5-6 and will also remove the linebreak of the entry in the last row. However, please note that thie will still roduce an overfull box warning since "Avhengighey:"  is too wide for an `X` column. To also prevent this, you could go for something like `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|l|}`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!